# Spring Boot can't find profile-specific properties files

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles

I am following [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties) to use profile specific property files for my SpringBoot app. I have 2 property files under `src/main/resources` : `datasource.properties` for local development and `datasource-prod.properties` for server datasource config.

This is my `DataSourceConfiguration.java` config class :

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:datasource-{profile}.properties")
@Slf4j
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

    @Value("${flad.datasource.driver}")
    private String dataSourceDriverClassName;
    @Value("${flad.datasource.url}")
    private String dataSourceUrl;
    @Value("${flad.datasource.username}")
    private String dataSourceUsername;
    @Value("${flad.datasource.password}")
    private String dataSourcePassword;

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataBase(){
        log.info("Datasource URL = {}", dataSourceUrl);
        return DataSourceBuilder
                .create()
                .driverClassName(dataSourceDriverClassName)
                .url(dataSourceUrl)
                .username(dataSourceUsername)
                .password(dataSourcePassword)
                .build();
    }
}
```

When I launch my SpringBootApplication main class I get the following error whether I use `-Dspring.profiles.active=prod` or not :

```
17:05:49.008 [restartedMain] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [fr.payet.flad.core.config.CoreConfig]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [datasource-{profile}.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Comment: I think this is not possible... https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12822

Comment: It worked for me for sometime but I have no idea why it doesn't anymore

Comment: maybe it was application-profile.properties ?

Comment: you mean `application-{profile}` ?

Comment: something like, yes but not with PropertySource since the use is discouraged

Comment: I found a solution that I don't like too much but it resolves my problem :) I'll post it below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that I found is to rename my property files `datasource-local.properties` and `datasource-prod.properties`, use @PropertySource this way `@PropertySource("classpath:datasource-${profile}.properties")` and when I launch my SpringBoot app I use `-Dprofile=local` as VM options